# Failed connection GeoServer with QGIS

Tags: qgis, geoserver

I have local GeoServer and QGIS 3.10. Everything was fine until yesterday. QGIS cannot connect to GeoServer. I have such image: 
[image]

GeoServer runs in normal mode with no errors in log file. There is no mention about connection attemp in GeoServer log. I've tried another QGIS version - 3.6 and there are no changes. What can go wrong with that connection?